# plugin unsupported: com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer @ 1.0.0

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I cannot find a replacement plugin for a videoplayer plugin I've been using for the past year.
Question:
To play local storage and/or online videos, what has been your way of implementing?  (And have you tried using the PhoneGap version cli-6.5.0?)  iFrame using the  tag does not work for me.  I have to assume it's because it's an app.

The dawsonloudon player isn't on NPM, so I'm a little stuck as to finding a suitable replacement.  And example code would be appreciated, as it feels like it is lacking

Comment: If that plugin is in GIT you can reference from there. For Video / Audio I use HTML5. I have only released on Android and HTML5 from local vs. http only works on Android 5+

Answer (score 1):

What I did to resolve this:
Since PhoneGap moved its plugin repository to NPM, the DawsonLouden plugin hasn't made it over to NPM.  So the build process essentially stopped because it couldn't find it.

What I did was bring the Dawson Louden plugin into the application, instead of making reference to the plugin via the config.xml.  This allows the plugin to be used internally versus grabbing it externally from the plugin repository.

Not being too familiar with plugins, I found an article which stepped me through how to download the Dawson Louden plugin code (via GitHub) and then use that plugin within my solution:
https://github.com/krisrandall/streaming-media-plugin-demo
Just make reference to the VideoPlayer GitHub project instead of the streaming media plugin project:
https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer

(also don't worry about the last 5 steps of the example...there is no demo project to download from GitHub).  You will have the plugin source code at this point anyways.

You should copy the source code for the plugin into the "plugins" folder within your PhoneGap project.

Then I instead of saying this in the config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer" version="1.0.0" />
```

Make reference to the local plugin in the config.xml using the feature tag:

```
<feature name="VideoPlayer" >
<param name="android-package" value="com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer"/>
</feature>
```

That was all it took.  One other note I discovered is that the VideoPlayer plugin didn't work on my Galaxy S5 but did on S6.